# Oracle text: catsearch does not support functional invocation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-text

Here's my setup:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(
  CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(9, 0) NOT NULL 
, CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR2(61 BYTE)
);

CREATE INDEX CTXCAT_CUSTOMER_NAME 
    ON CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_NAME) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CTXCAT;
```

My (simplified) query:

```
select /*+ INDEX(customer CTXCAT_CUSTOMER_NAME)*/* 
from customer
where CATSEARCH(customer_name,'ltd Anderson',null) > 0 or customer_id > 100
```

Error:

> Error starting at line 1 in command: select /*+ INDEX(customer
>   CTXCAT_CUSTOMER_NAME)*/*  from customer where
>   CATSEARCH(customer_name,'ltd Anderson',null) > 0 or customer_id > 100
>   Error report: SQL Error: ORA-20000: Oracle Text error: DRG-10849:
>   catsearch does not support functional invocation
>   20000. 00000 -  "%s"
>   *Cause:    The stored procedure 'raise_application_error'
>              was called which causes this error to be generated.
>   *Action:   Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact
>              the application administrator or DBA for more information.

The HINT suggestion came from here: https://forums.oracle.com/message/2847094 and clearly doesn't work for me.

Any ideas how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that most probably in your query Oracle uses `CATSEARCH` as a function invocation, rather than using your index. This is because you have the OR condition and Oracle has to check every row in your table. That's also the reason why HINT won't help. Can you show us the execution plan?

Perhaps try this:

```
select * 
from customer
where customer_id > 100
UNION
select /*+ INDEX(customer CTXCAT_CUSTOMER_NAME)*/ *
from customer
where CATSEARCH(customer_name,'ltd Anderson',null) > 0;
```

(the hint shouldn't be necessary in above example)

Comment: sorry, i can't show a proper query plan as I'd need to insert around 3M rows to demonstrate. I don't understand why the hint won't work. 'UNION' is not an option as it may result in duplicates.

Comment: @Chuck `UNION` removes duplicates (`UNION ALL` could return duplicates). Can you try it? The hint doesn't work because what Oracle needs to do: check the records that satisfy the CATSEARCH condition. Some of those that do not satisfy it may satisfy the other condition, tho, so Oracle has to go through all rows again (or use index on customer_id). Now there may be some that satisfy both conditions and they would have to be removed from the result set cause they were picked up by the first condition - and here Oracle's decides to do a full scan (I think) and the CTXCAT index is not used.